# PopUp Window Size Guidelines

Tags: user-expectation, popup, responsive

I am currently working at a project, where I have to specify a pop up window size for a 4k Screen. I am not sure how big I should go with the background of the pop up. Are there any design rules when it comes to Pop ups and bigger display sizes? I just found guidelines for smaller display sizes.

For Example for Desktop I use 990 as PopUp size and for Tablet 744.

Has anyone experience with this? Does the User want a size that is related to the display size or could I just use the popup window size I used for the desktop? I am very grateful for any help or information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be it depends on the size of the screen you are using. For a 32" screen size 1400 px is the ideal size (assuming you haven't changed the display scaling to anything higher or lower than 100%)